# "1.5 hours" are "One hour and half" or "One and half hour"?

Tags: sentence-structure

**1.5 hours** are "One hour and half" or "One and half hours"?

Examples:

> He will be there in 1.5 hours.
>
> I spend there 1.5 hours.

Answer (score 2):

It's either "one and a half hour**s**" (plural because it's more than one hour)  or "one/an hour and a half".

Comment: Or "an hour and a half" (more common in relaxed speech).

Comment: What about "an hour and half" (without "a")? I've seen it used a lot.

Comment: @Jan-Re: "I've seen it used a lot", [see here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+hour+and+half%2Can+hour+and+a+half&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20hour%20and%20half%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20hour%20and%20a%20half%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Can%20hour%20and%20half%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20hour%20and%20a%20half%3B%2Cc0) and pay attention to the date of usage.